# UIButton TouchUpInside not being fired, but pointInside:withEvent: returns YES

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` on which I attached an `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` action. This button is inserted in a `UIScrollView`.

My problem is: touch events won't work until I hold on the button for a certain time. If I tap  on it directly, or just click on it in the simulator, it won't work.

The thing is: when I just click on it, `pointInside:withEvent:` is actually triggered and returns `YES`. What could possibly prevent the event from being fired?

Comment: Is it possible that some other view is higher in the *[responder chain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html)*, consuming the touch event before it can reach the `UIButton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `delaysContentTouches` property of your scrollView to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work so you can check the following eg.:

1) make sure that you button is properly added to scrollview. For example like this:

```
    ...
    myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    myScrollView.bounces = NO;
    [myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    myScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    myScrollView.delegate = self;
    myScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myScrollView];
    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*5, 480);
    ...
    UIButton *mybutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
    mybutton.tag = 1
    [mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedmybutton:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myScrollView addSubview:bu];
```

2) make sure that button is top of the view stack. For testing purpose add at the end of the view init code [mybutton bringSubviewToFront];

3) test it on device and not just in Simulator. I experienced different scrolling/button pressing behavior in Simulator than on real device (which is the better for testing this out).